# Why is same assembly code not working on my computer?

Tags: linux, parsing, assembly

I am **total beginner** to ASM and I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-QTsadgHWc&index=6&list=PLpU1XT9z0vpuLVXKTHKxBB4l6f3ugNt3i). Code in this example is not working. I am using Linux Mint and both on my 64bit computer and 32bit laptop nasm is displaying same errors:

```
rad.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
rad.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
rad.asm:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
rad.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected
rad.asm:4: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
rad.asm:13: error: comma, colon or end of line expected
rad.asm:19: error: parser: instruction expected
```

This is the code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
dexter db "Hello$"

.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset dexter
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end start
```

I have successfully installed nasm because other "Hello World" examples I can compile successfully using:

```
nasm -f elf name.asm
ld name.o -o test
./test
```

**Does NASM for Windows compile code different that NASM for Linux?**

Comment: That is 16 bit DOS code, that won't work on linux. It will work in a dos emulator such as dosbox. Also it is not `nasm` syntax, the tutorial uses `tasm`.

Comment: No, but Nasm needs to assemble different code for Windows/Linux. What you've got there is DOS code in Masm/Tasm syntax.